# Can I use the same id on different xmls?

Tags: android

I have about 20 different xml files, and all of them has a raitingBar on them, and I have only one Activity for all of them, so my question is , can I use the same id for all of the raitingBar on the xml files?

Comment: yes, you can; xml id later become R.id.${name} at this point we can't say this constants belongs to which layout. only matter when we access it via view.findViewById()

Comment: But in the java, will it refrence all of them? I mean the one on the current xml

Comment: Since the findViewById method is called for the current view only, yes you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, In Android all specified XML IDs finally at build time will be some integers in `R.id.*` class.

For example suppose you create this XML item:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    ... />
```

The statement `android:id="@+id/text"` tells Android that add a new (because of `+` sign) ID called *text* into the `R.id` class. For example it takes some iteger like `123`.

At this point, you define another view in another XML file with the same ID :

```
<TextView android:id="@id/text"
    ... />
```

Now in your Java codes, for example you use `layout_1.xml` (the first one) and then making a call `findViewById(R.id.text)`. Keep in mind that all `R.id.*` is type of Integers (those are not some strange objects !)

So this statement is interpreted as `findViewById(123)`. If you remember you've used only `layout_1.xml` file and in this file only **one** view exists with the ID `R.id.text` = `123`. So this call will target **only one** view at the `layout_1.xml` not all your views in another XML files. That's it :)

Note: Try avoiding use same ID in same XML file.